# Little Big Planet ONE

Tags: little-big-planet

I always wait for other people to come at a level.They never show up.Is it just because my internet is horrible or no one is playing?

Comment: By "at a level" do you mean when you try playing on a world, no-one comes to play with you?

Comment: I doubt there are many people playing anymore so that is likely to be your issue. You could try looking on forums for people to play with. I am sure there are still people out there looking to 100% the game if that is what you are after.

Answer (score 1):

The first reason is more than likely becasue next to no one is still playing the first installment of the series just about everyone is on the 3rd LBP playing it or a few might still be on the 2nd game. Another reason could be your Internet not having good signal strength to connect with compatible players. That is all I can really think of hope this helps you out.